# Need to write a python program to print words which are repeated number of times a number given as input from a text file of larger size

Tags: python

Need to write a python program to print "The words which are repeated in a text file of larger size, giving an input a numerical value"

example
task.txt [apple basket apple orange apple basket lemon basket]
textfile contains different words separated by space

```
my python program
with open('task.txt') as f:
    string = f.read()
  
string = string.lower();  
n = int(input("enter number :"))
    
words = string.split(" ");  
   
print("the words which are repeated given number of times : ");  
for i in range(0, len(words)):  
    count = 1;  
    for j in range(i+1, len(words)):  
        if(words[i] == (words[j])):  
            count = count + 1;   
            words[j] = "0";    
    if(count == n and words[i] != "0"):  
        print(words[i]); 
    else:
        print('no word found')
        break;
```

output

```
enter number :3
the words which are repeated at a given number of times : 
apple
basket
```

code is working fine but the issue is how to read data in chunks if the file size is 100 GB

Comment: Read it line by line if the words can't span multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

Read the file a line at a time instead of reading the whole thing.

You can use `collections.Counter()` to get the counts of each word, then go through this to find all the ones that were repeated at least `n` times.

```
import collections

word_counts = collections.Counter()

with open('task.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        word_counts.update(line.lower().split())

n = int(input("enter number :"))
print("the words which are repeated given number of times : ");  
words = [word for word, count in word_counts.items() if count >= n]
if len(words) == 0:
    print('no word found')
else:
    print(*words, sep = '\n')
```